# AWS Load balancer SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-certificate-manager

I have a SSL certificate created in the "certificate manager" in the console, (as I use to do always). In this case it is for a subdomain (wildcard) *.mydomain.co.uk certificate, but for some reason, when I load the site in the browser, the certificate is not "loaded". These is what I did:

1. A wildcard certificate was created in the "Certificate manager"
2. I chose the DNS validation, and after add the Cname records to Route53, the subdomain was validated.
3. In the load balancer used by the ELB environment, I attached this certificate for my subdomain  *.mydomain.co.uk. (this is the normal procedure I always do, and this is the first time I have this issue).

What I did wrong?

Note: The domain is parked outside AWS, but the NS records points to my AWS account and I can manage the subdomain DNS configuration by Route 53 (that's why I was able to validate the domain).
Could be an issue where the domain was registered and not in my configuration (AWS side)?

Comment: So you are entering `https://some-subdomain.mydomain.co.uk` into your web browser, and that specific subdomain points to your load balancer via a CNAME or Route53 Alias record, and you get some sort of certificate error?

Comment: I did not get any error , but the certificate is not working (I only see the message "nos secure site...". The subdomain (not the domain), is in Route 53 , and the certificate is attached to the loadbalancer, I have not idea what is happening , because I always add my certificates in the same way and this is the first time I have an issue (maybe because it is a subdomain?). I tried to create a certificate wildcad *.mydomain and an specific certificate for the subdomain, both are no working.

Comment: Like Mark mentioned, you could be hitting your subdomain using HTTP which is the reason of the error. Recommending below checks:

1) Using command line check the DNS lookup to confirm that it is pointing at the ALB
2) Using `https://` in the browser url when attempting. You may also use curl to test this as below:

`curl -lvk https://<your sub domain>`

The test should show the IP address you are connecting to and the Certificate if you get any. 

If the above test is working, you may want to set the ALB to have a redirect rule on HTTP listener to HTTPS

Comment: My good guys, I feel very stupid now!! :), I thought  that the loadbalancer was redirecting the http petitions to https ,but it was not true, that's the reason why the cert id not work, very stupid issue.  Thanks very much!